# Why are flags on obsolete comments being denied?

Tags: discussion, flagging, moderation

Three flags on obsolete comments were denied.

> Can you post the photos to imgur and put a link to them in your post or in the comments, so we can edit them in? – ThreePhaseEel Dec 7 at 23:14
>
> "I don't see a way to post it here." Then you haven't looked very hard. That indicates the chance you successfully fixing your device are slim, and spending time on this question is unlikely to be fruitful. – Olin Lathrop Dec 8 at 0:02
>
> (5) Your question title says "Controlling two leds with one digital output". The post says, "I have a RGB led ...". Can you fix that too? – Transistor Nov 27 at 21:50

Issue was fixed in both cases and the comments were made obsolete. Why?

Comment: Link to the post in question, please.

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/342178/controlling-two-leds-with-one-digital-output

Comment: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/343890/i-have-bad-sot-23-because-its-swollen-and-leaking

Comment: Why would you flag those comments in the first place?

Comment: @PlasmaHH As the question states: They were made obsolete due to edits. Leaving them could be very confusing for later visitors. There's nothing strange with flagging them since there is a flag option literally designed for obsolete comments.

Comment: @pipe -- exactly.   I'm not the greatest at cleaning up comments myself, so thanks for looking out for me on that one :)

Answer (score 11):

I don't know why the flags were denied. Those comments, as well as others, were clearly made obsolete by subsequent edits of the associated posts. I've gone through and cleaned things up.